# Prevent last key in string to have a comma

Tags: c#

Having trouble figuring out how to prevent the last key in my array to not have a comma. Since its being exported to a .Json file the last key shouldn't have a ",".

I know you can detect it by using `.Last();`, but I can't seem to make that work. Any recommendations?

```
//Data Path
string dataPath = @"..\..\FileIOExtraFiles\DataFieldsLayout.txt";
string[] dataList = File.ReadAllLines(dataPath);
//save Data data

using (StreamWriter outStream = new StreamWriter(outputFolder + @"\CharacterStringData3.json"))
{
    outStream.WriteLine("{");
    for (int i = 0; i < dataFile.Length; i++)
    {
        string s = dataFile[i];
        char last = s.Last();
        if (s == "")
        {
            outStream.WriteLine("\"" + dataList[i] + "\"" + " : " + "\" \",");
        }
        else
        {
            outStream.WriteLine("\"" + dataList[i] + "\"" + " : \"" + s + "\",");
        }
    }
    outStream.WriteLine("}");
}
```

Output:

```
{
 "data1":"item1",
 "data2":item2",
 "lastKey":item3",//trying to remove comma from last key in array.
}
```

Comment: perhaps you should use a package like JSON.NET

Comment: why on earth are you building json manually

Comment: At least he's using USING!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have pointed out, it doesn't make sense that you are building json manually, but given that this is a question more about technique, here is one approach: you could change it to this:

```
var commaSuffix = (i == dataFile.Length - 1) ? "," : string.Empty;
outStream.WriteLine("\"" + dataList[i] + "\"" + " : \"" + s + "\"" + commaSuffix);
```

The suffix would be used on every iteration except the last.

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
outStream.WriteLine("\"" + dataList[i] + "\"" + " : " + "\" \",");
```

To this

```
outStream.WriteLine("\"" + dataList[i] + "\"" + " : " + "\" \""+(i==dataFile.Length?",":""));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `outStream.WriteLine()` at every step, store it in a string. Then you can remove the last comma from that string and write the whole string at once:

```
//Get last index of comma
int lastCommaIndex = outputString.LastIndexOf(',');

//Create new StringBuilder with everything before the last comma
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(outputString.Substring(0,lastCommaIndex));

//Add everything after the last comma, or just add a closing brace
//sb.Append("}"); //This instead of next line
sb.Append(outputString.Substring(lastCommaIndex+1));

//Add contents of StringBuilder to the Stream
outSteam.WriteLine(sb);
```

Comment: This is pretty inefficient. I would go with one of the answers that checks `i` against `dataFile.Length`